# How can I suppress the exception message when downloading an image through Firebase storage in an Android Compose function?

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, android-jetpack-compose, task

I have this snippet of code inside of a Compose function in Android. I am trying to download some images related to my users, but some of these images may not exist (the users might have not uploaded them yet). Right now everything works and in that case it shows a default image, but every time an image is not found I get a big red stack trace in the Logcat. Since this is an expected exception, is there any way to handle this? I'm okay with logging something, but I would like to avoid to make it look like an unexpected behaviour.

```kotlin
val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference.child("profileImages/${friend.id}")
var imageUrl: Uri? by remember { mutableStateOf(null) }
var showDefaultImage by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

storageReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
    imageUrl = it
}.addOnFailureListener {
    showDefaultImage = true
    Log.d("IMAGE URL", it.message ?: "")
}
```

`friend` is an object parameter that contains the information about the user.

I would have expected that handling the exception message that the failure listener passes would have avoided for the exception to be logged (outside of my own log), but that does not seem to be the case.